What's this bandage around Lawrence/Gomer Pyle's wrist during target practice?
While Lawrence/Gomer Pyle is at the shooting range, he has what looks like a bandage around his right wrist. Nobody else on the range is wearing any wrist equipment so I don't think it has anything to do with the exercise, and I don't think the character wears it at any other point in the film. Given Kubrick's perfectionism and the fact that the bandage is in the center of the action I felt it was worth investigating.


Its also the subject of a continuity error: https://www.moviemistakes.com/picture3209 "he is wearing a white wrist wrap/brace but the shot moves behind him and it is gone. Back to the right side and it reappears. (00:35:50)"

Note: https://i.sstatic.net/J989T62C.png - worth noting that when he cleans his rifle, he has two cloths: one with which he is cleaning working parts, and another wrapped around his hand. The next two shots are on the range, with the cloth wrapped around right wrist, then with it wrapped around his left wrist instead.

@blobbymcblobby - I don't think that's the same cloth. The one on his wrist is pristeen white and wrapped like a bandage. The other is (as you'd expect from a cleaning rag) a murky grey colour

ah,  i didn't mean to say that the cleaning cloth was the same as on  his wrist cloth

I don't have an answer, but watching the scene I do notice that the bandage shifts to the character's left wrist when the camera angle switches to over the shoulder looking downrange. Odd. Likely indicates it wasn't because of an actual injury to the actor.

It may be a reference to an incident from the source novel, The Short-Timers by Gustav Hasford, where a recruit who was suffering a mental breakdown and attempted to kill himself. The last we see of Perkins is him heading off to the sick bay to get a bandage to his wrist.

Sergeant Gerheim is careful not to come down too hard on Leonard as
long as Leonard remains squared away. We have already lost seven
recruits on Section Eight discharges. A Kentucky boy named Perkins
stepped to the center of the squad bay and slashed his wrists with his
bayonet. Sergeant Gerheim was not happy to see a recruit bleeding upon
his nice clean squad bay. The recruit was ordered to police the area,
mop up the blood, and replace the bayonet in its sheath. While Perkins
mopped up the blood, Sergeant Gerheim called a school circle and
poo-pooed the recruit's shallow slash across his wrists with a
bayonet. The U.S.M.C.—approved method of recruit suicide is to get
alone and take a razor blade and slash deep and vertical, from wrist
to elbow, Sergeant Gerheim said. Then he allowed Perkins to
double-time to sick bay.
Sergeant Gerheim leaves Leonard alone and concentrates on the rest of
us.

Note that this incident occurs only a handful of paragraphs away from us seeing Leonard receiving special commendation for his shooting prowess.

On the third day of our seventh week we move to the rifle range and shoot holes in paper targets. Sergeant Gerheim brags about the marksmanship of ex-Marines Charles Whitman and Lee Harvey Oswald.
By the end of our seventh week Leonard has become a model recruit. We
decide that Leonard's silence is a result of his new intense
concentration. Day by day, Leonard is more motivated, more squared
away. His manual of arms is flawless now, but his eyes are milk glass.


i saw this too, but wasn't sure how it impacted with Leonard, since there is no mention of it (but i have not looked for old scripts). Also might be a weird either on-set or editing issue, apparently the missing bandage is on his other wrist when in another shot. As for injuries during shooting much is made of Vincents knee injuries and overall health due to excessive weight gain (and R.Lee Ermeys car crash) but nothing about his wrist, so perhaps, as you say, related to an ..unseen ..scene ...

@blobbymcblobby - Kubrick was a big fan of the original book and read it multiple times; https://www.slashfilm.com/1148450/full-metal-jackets-original-author-wasnt-happy-with-what-he-saw-on-stanley-kubricks-set/.

I know this, I thought the book was great too, I was just talking out loud about an unseen scene.. if any, that makes more of the wrist.

@blobbymcblobby - I don't know about the shooting order, but Kubrick may have had plans to include this scene. Having Leonard have a bandage would have given him that option.

I am aware that Modine's diary mentions cut/unfilmed scenes (sex scene, etc), but I have not read it, I wonder if there's anything in there...

Not clarifying anything but just noting that a cloth appears on his left hand (in addition to the one he is using to clean with) in the barracks cleaning shot, then he has it on the right wrist on the range, and in the same scene has it now on his left wrist: https://i.sstatic.net/J989T62C.png - perhaps just continuity errors?

@blobbymcblobby - Almost certainly just a continuity error. It's also possible that it's actually on the correct wrist, but that the shot has been mirrored.

I checked for the flip, but the M14 charging handle (operating rod) is on the correct (right) side, so yeah, the wrap changed sides. I will possibly correct the cleaning scene though, it might be that the cloth is so long that he wrapped it multiple times around his hand and then had a little extra length with which to clean the rifle.

@blobbymcblobby - While that's true, it's also not unheard-of for a costume maker or propmaster to make a reversed version of an item

Wearing a wrist bandage is pretty common when practicing gymnastics, weight lifting & strength training, shooting... etc... All of these activities require a lot of severe physical constraints around the wrist (where the carpal tunnel is located), and the bandage helps reduce the strain on the wrist and some of the blood vessels, thus, pain.
Snipers often wear such reinforcement bandage under a wrist equipement (like holding spare bullets).
It's not script related or in-universe per se, but rather an everyday life detail/hack that might have been used in the movie for more resemblance to real life. The character might have been hurt during some training, or suffered from previous shooting session.
